# Trying to install Sass Rails Source Maps and failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

I'm trying to install the [Sass Rails Source Maps](https://github.com/vhyza/sass-rails-source-maps) on my ruby project but it's failing.

Im getting the next error when writing `bundle update sass`:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "sass":

In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (~> 4.0.3) ruby depends on
      sass (~> 3.2.0) ruby
```

In my Gemfile I have the next related gems:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'sass', '~> 3.3.7'
group :development do
    gem 'sass-rails-source-maps'
end
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it doesn't fit, even master branch uses `'sass', '~> 3.2'`.

As a solution you can fork `sass-rails` and update `sass-rails.gemspec` with `s.add_dependency 'sass', '>= 3.2'` instead of `'~> 3.2'` and use it in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'sass-rails', github: 'your_nick/sass-rails' # your_nick - your username on Github
```

I couldn't work, but you can try.